# Why there are no initializers or class constructor in class-transofrmer demo?

Tags: typescript, class-transformer

```
import { Expose, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

class User {
  @Expose() id: number;
  @Expose() firstName: string;
  @Expose() lastName: string;
}

const fromPlainUser = {
  unkownProp: 'hello there',
  firstName: 'Umed',
  lastName: 'Khudoiberdiev',
};
```

This is the demo from [class-transformer's document](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/). Here is my question: isn't `User` a invalid Typescript Class, since It doesn't have any initializers for properties or constructor?
In fact, after I copyed this demo into IDE, I immediately got the `ts(2564): Property 'id' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor` error

Comment: _"isn't `User` a invalid Typescript Class"_ this depends on your `tsconfig.json`. In some of my projects this is allowed and in others it's not allowed, e.g. in a default Angular project it's allowed but in a strict Angular project it's not allowed. You could ask the same question about the decorators `@Expose()`. In my default projects decorators are not allowed. I have to enable them in the `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: _"Why there are no initializers or class constructor in class-transofrmer demo?"_ This question can only be answered by the authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"isn't `User` a invalid Typescript Class"*

It's invalid if

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "strict": true
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and valid if

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "strict": false
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

in `tsconfig.json`.

> `--strict`
>
> Enable all strict type checking options. Enabling `--strict` enables
> `--noImplicitAny`, `--noImplicitThis`, `--alwaysStrict`, `--strictBindCallApply`, `--strictNullChecks`, `--strictFunctionTypes` and `--strictPropertyInitialization`.

[[Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options)]

It's actually `strictNullChecks`.